# Dancer not save data in sqlite after reboot

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi, dancer

```
sub connect_db {
       my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=".setting('database')) or
               die $DBI::errstr;

       return $dbh;
}

sub init_db {
       my $db = connect_db();
       my $schema = read_file('./schema.sql');
       $db->do($schema) or die $db->errstr;
}


get '/' => sub {
       my $db = connect_db();
       my $sql = 'select id, title, text from entries order by id desc';
       my $sth = $db->prepare($sql) or die $db->errstr;
       $sth->execute or die $sth->errstr;
       template 'show_entries.tt', {
               'msg' => get_flash(),
               'add_entry_url' => uri_for('/add'),
               'entries' => $sth->fetchall_hashref('id'),
       };
};
```

Why after reboot system entries in database not saved ? Size databases not increment.
why is this happening ?

Comment: Your code does not save any items to the database.

Comment: What do you expect to see saved to the database? There's no code that saves anything. The `init_db()` subroutine looks like it's meant to set up a database schema, but it's not called from any code you have shown us.

Comment: init_db() called in the end of code. How to do it ?

Comment: Complete code here https://github.com/PerlDancer/dancer-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The sample script https://github.com/PerlDancer/dancer-tutorial/blob/master/dancr.pl, which you're probably using, is explicitly creating the database file in the default temporary directory:

```
set 'database' => File::Spec->catfile(File::Spec->tmpdir(), 'dancr.db');
```

Probably your system in configured to clean /tmp (or whatever the temporary directory is) after reboots, or maybe /tmp is located on a memory file system.

If you want a persistent database, then change the location of the database.

Comment: Then i have the following question, Why was it necessary to create a database use this code   <code>  $ cat - | sqlite3 database 
    create table if not exists entries (
        id integer primary key autoincrement,
        title string not null,
        text string not null
    );
    ^D  </code>

Comment: This is a new question.